# Why is assignment within a predicate allowed in Apex?

Tags: apex

Why does Apex allow this?:

```
Boolean b = false;
if (b = true)
    System.debug('Equal!');
else
    System.debug('Not equal');
```

But flag this with the error 'Condition expression must be of type Boolean':

```
Integer a = 1, b = 2;
if (a = b)
    System.debug('Equal!');
else
    System.debug('Not equal');
```

Assignment within a predicate shouldn't ever be allowed in my view.  Why does Apex permit this when the variable is a Boolean?

Answer (score 9):

That's because in both scenarios: (b = true) and (a = b) is an expression. Every expression (usually combined with some variables and operators) can be considered as a function which returns a value. For example, a = b not only does the assignment, it also returns the value of a.

If that is clear, you can see the condition expression inside the if() statement is nothing but a value. You can simply do this:

```
if(true)
{
     //...
}
```

or

```
if(a)
{
    //...
}
```

In the second case, a has to be of type Boolean. That's why in your case, Scenario 1 is Okay to compile and Scenario 2 is not.

As we understand this can easily lead to unwanted bugs. One good practice can be writing similar code like below:

```
if(true == b)
{
    //...
}
```

Which will help you finding out the issue at the first glance.

Comment: Thanks Lance.  In my experience the value of doing any sort of assignment within a predicate is almost always unintentional and accidental which can then lead to 'unwanted bugs' as you say.  Seeing that the Apex compiler flagged the issue when the Integer types were being assigned I was surprised to see that changing the variable type to a boolean had a different result.  The obvious change to address the issue in this case is to use "if (b)" when b is a Boolean but that wasn't how code (and bug) I found were originally implemented.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few cases where this behaviour is useful in e.g. Java (reading files):

```
while((s = br.readLine()) != null) { ... }
```

or C (strcpy):

```
while ((*s++ = *s2++) != 0);
```

or in Apex tests (where `contact` is a field of a fixture class);

```
insert contact = new Contact(FirstName = 'Jane', LastName = 'Doe');
```

Comment: I guess I've grown pretty allergic over the years to performing assignments within predicates since they so often lead to difficult to read code and unintentional bugs.  When I saw that the Apex compiler did what I thought was the correct thing when there was an unintentional assignment with Integers, I was surprised to see a different result when variables were Booleans.